# how I could do a gsub with array elements?

Tags: ruby, gsub

How I could replaces a string like this

I think something like this

```
inputx.gsub(/variable1/,string1.split(";")[i])
```

But I dont know How I could do this code

```
name1;variable1 
name;variable1 
name3;variable1
```

by

```
dog;watch;rock
```

For obtain this

```
name1;dog
name;watch
name3;rock
```

string1 => dog;watch;rock ; this string Im trying to split for replace each string variable1

Please help me

Comment: string1 => dog;watch;rock  ; this string Im trying to split for replace each string variable1

Comment: What is `name1;variable1 name;variable1 name3;variable1`? An array containing three strings, i.e. `["name1;variable1", "name;variable1", "name3;variable1"]` or a single multi-line string, i.e. `"name1;variable1\nname;variable1\nname3;variable1"` or something else?

Comment: Try to formulate your sentences in english please. I didn't downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure there's a way to do it using `.gsub()`. One simple way to achieve what you want to is the following:

```
str = "dog;watch;rock"

array = str.split(";")

array.each_with_index do |str, i|
    array[i] = "name#{i + 1};#{str}"
end

puts array
```

Output:

```
name1;dog
name2;watch
name3;rock
```

Comment: very thankyou for your response ; I solve too I will public another solution

Answer (score 2):

```
subst = "dog;watch;rock".split ';'
input.gsub(/variable1/) do subst.shift end
#⇒ "name1;dog \n   name;watch \n   name3;rock"
```

Answer (score 1):

Given (assuming) this input:

```
inputx = <<-EOD
name1;variable1
name;variable1
name3;variable1
EOD
#=> "name1;variable1\nname;variable1\nname3;variable1\n"

string1 = 'dog;watch;rock'
#=> "dog;watch;rock"
```

You can chain `gsub` and [`with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) to perform a replacement based on its index:

```
inputx.gsub('variable1').with_index { |_, i| string1.split(';')[i] }
#=> "name1;dog\nname;watch\nname3;rock\n"
```

You could also perform the `split` beforehand:

```
values = string1.split(';')
#=> ["dog", "watch", "rock"]

inputx.gsub('variable1').with_index { |_, i| values[i] }
#=> "name1;dog\nname;watch\nname3;rock\n"
```

Answer (score -1):

file intro2 => dog;watch;rock

file intro

```
name1;variable1 
  name;variable1 
 name3;variable1
```

ruby code

```
  ruby  -e   '   n=0; input3= File.read("intro");string1= File.read("intro2")    ;input3x=input3.gsub("variable1") { val =string1.split(";")[n].to_s; n+=1; val }  ;print input3x' >gggf
```